# How to find A given the exponent and it's modulo and remainder

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

So quick question: if I have this thing: 
$A^e mod B = C$

I know the values of e (exponent of A), B (the mod) and C (the remainder). How do I find out what the value of **A** is?

I am kinda stuck and have a deadline in 2 hours and would really appreciate a little hint on this :) Thanks in advance =)

Cheers,
A

Comment: [Discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)

Comment: This is  known as discrete logarithm problem. It is quite a challenging one  and no general way to solve it exists. Google it

Comment: problem is not to start before the deadline expires, but to ASK before the deadline expires. I am working on other questions of the assignment since Saturday. I ask in the last moment, cause till the last moment I try to solve things myself and only ask when I am really stuck. But thank you for the advice, @DietrichBurde

To anyone else who helped instead of being mean, THANK YOU. I will try to calculate things now :)